# Properties of complex type are null or default in controller action argument upon AJAX POST call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I have gone through several posts here with similar issues and have tried several alternatives suggested here but with no luck.

I am trying to make a AJAX POST call from javascript to my controller action developed in .NET CORE 2.1. The action receives a complex object as argument.

Please find the details below.

**AJAX CALL:**

```
var scanRequest = {
        GUID: guid,
        UserEmail: email,
        ApplicationURL: appURL,
        ApplicationName: appName,
        SelectedAppTimezone: appTimeZone,
        ScheduledScanTime: schScnTime,
        SelectedLocation: location,
        SelectedPrimaryContactTimezone: appPriTimeZone,
        AdditionalContacts: addContacts,
        APMID: apmID,
        OwningTerritory: ownTerritory,
        SelectedLineOfService: los,
        ScanAuthenticationRequired: scnAuthReq,
        ScanAuthenticationDetails: scanAuthDetails
    };


    var source = JSON.stringify(scanRequest);

    var actionURL = "/ScanRequest/NewScanRequest";

    $.ajax({
        url: actionURL,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'request': source },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modalContent').modal('show');
            $("#modalbodyContent").html(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewScanRequest( ScanRequest request)
    {
        .....
     }
```

**Complex Class**

```
public class ScanRequest
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationURL { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAppTimezone { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AppTimezones { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledScanTime { get; set; }
    public string SelectedLocation { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPrimaryContactTimezone { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalContacts { get; set; }
    public string APMID { get; set; }   
    public string OwningTerritory { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LineOfServices { get; set; }
    public string SelectedLineOfService { get; set; }
    public bool ScanAuthenticationRequired { get; set; }
    public string ScanAuthenticationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

After debugging the JS, I figured out that the object is getting stringified, even the **data** parameter of the AJAX request also contains the required data. When the request hits the controller action, the object is appearing but its internal properties are either null or have default values and does not contain the values posted through the form. I have tried using **[FromBody]** attribute as well but then the object itself is null when it reaches the controller action. I have attached the screenshots of the request headers, the request payload as well.

[Image : parameter in action (without [FromBody])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D033U.png);[Image : parameter in action (with [FromBody])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJLGq.png) ; [Image : Request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3MYV.png) ; [Image : Request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2s06.png)
If anyone can kindly help me out in this regard it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the ModelState while stopped on a breakpoint in the beginning of the POST method, it will tell you if there are any errors when desirializing the payload into your object.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not get you completely. Can you please elaborate on how to place the debugger before the post method. If possible can u please share the code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your controller is not specified with the `[ApiController]` attribute and you'd like to pass parameter/data from the body of an HTTP request, to achieve it, you can refer to the following working sample to modify your code.

*Controller And Action*

```
public class ScanRequestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewScanRequest([FromBody]ScanRequest request) //Apply the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter
    {
        // code logic here
    }

    //code of other controller actions 
}
```

*Javascript client side with testing data*

```
var scanRequest = {
    GUID: "7c3151ca-426a-4ddb-8a48-26a8b9b06b24",
    UserEmail: "test@example.com",
    ApplicationURL: "http://test.com",
    ApplicationName: "app1",
    SelectedAppTimezone: "Pacific Standard Time",
    ScheduledScanTime: "2020-02-10T11:03:15.4502335+08:00",
    SelectedLocation: "location1",
    SelectedPrimaryContactTimezone: "Pacific Standard Time",
    AdditionalContacts: "",
    APMID: "",
    OwningTerritory: "",
    SelectedLineOfService: "l11",
    ScanAuthenticationRequired: true,
    ScanAuthenticationDetails: "details"
};

var source = JSON.stringify(scanRequest);

var actionURL = "/ScanRequest/NewScanRequest";

$.ajax({
    url: actionURL,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: source,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
        //$('#modalContent').modal('show');
        //$("#modalbodyContent").html(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Hello... thanks for your reply.. My controller is not decorated with [ApiController] attribute. I tried with [FromBody] attribute as well.. But in that case the request object itself is null. I have attached the screenshot for the same as well.. if you can plz go through that..

Comment: Hi... I tried it once again adding the [FromBody] attribute in the controller action and modifying the data parameter in Ajax post call... Like "data:source" instead of "data:{request: source}" and it worked... Thanks a lot for your answer. But can you plz suggest that was it the way I was passing the parameter through the Ajax call tat this was not being detected?

Comment: If it did help resolve the problem, you can [accept the reply as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).